# Justification for new theories of Particle Physics and General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, standard-model, dark-matter, dark-energy

In reference to [arxiv:1212.4893v3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4893v3) and [arxiv:1206.5078v2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5078v2) papers of Ma and Wang, they have proposed new theories in particle physics, the weakton model where quarks and leptons are formed using these weaktons; modified Einstein's field equations taking care of Dark matter and Energy.

Are these really major breakthroughs as they apparently seem to be, with proper experimental evidences of their accuracy ? Or are they yet to be verified ? What does the Physics community think of these ? I am curious.

Comment: I got to page 3 of the GR paper, and at that point I lost count of the number of crackpot indicators I saw (over a dozen). "EFEs failed to explain the dark matter and dark energy" (of course they fail there - they are equations of motion, and they say nothing about what exists in the universe); no solution for CMB in spherical symmetry (so hundreds of cosmologists all missed this fact for the last century?); looking to the EFEs to explain inhomogeneity; the list goes on.

Comment: The modified gravitation is just another gravitational theory with a scalar field. There are so much of these, and they are used both for dark energy and dark matter explanations (and Ma and Wang are certainly not the first ones to propose such a thing). For a taste of some of the other theories and why observational cosmologists really cannot really care about every new variation see [this question and answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123131/what-are-the-alternative-theories-of-dark-energy-w-neq-1).

Answer (score 13):

I am an experimental physicists, and the model in the first paper has not reached the level of experimental predictions, for LHC results. In fact except for the link you give the search at the CERN document server gives nothing, and the word "weakton" does not yield discussions or appraisals. So the experimental physics community is overlooking this, even though some people at the LHC look at [composite models.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.7311v1.pdf), look at paragraph 4.1.

From what I see of the [submission history](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4893) it has not been peer reviewed to appear in a standard journal although it is a year since it is in the archive.

Lets see if a theoretical physicist has a response to this question for the particle paper.

**Edit** after comment

Now for the new gravitational theory paper, I found [an article](http://newsinfo.iu.edu/news-archive/23053.html) popularizing it,

> "Most importantly, this new energy and the new field equations offer a unified theory for both dark energy and dark matter, which until now have been considered as two totally different beasts sharing only 'dark' in name," he said. "Both dark matter and dark energy can now be represented by the sum of the new scalar potential energy density and the coupling energy between the energy-momentum tensor and the scalar potential field."
>
> The negative part of this sum represents the dark matter, which produces attraction, and the positive part represents the dark energy, which drives the acceleration of expanding galaxies, he said.
>
> "In a nutshell, we believe that new gravity theory will change our view on energy, gravitational interactions, and the structure and formation of our universe," Wang(an author) said.
>
> Kevin Zumbrun, chair of the Department of Mathematics at IU Bloomington, said the new unified theory looked sound in principle.
>
> "It is speculative at the cosmological level, since one must match with experiment, but the math is solid," he said. "It's a new and elegant angle on things, and if this does match experiment, it is a huge discovery. Quite exciting!"
>
> Wang (an author) said the new field equations also lead to a modified Newtonian gravitational force formula, which shows that dark matter plays a more important role in a galactic scale at about 1,000 to 100,000 light years, but is less important in the larger scale, where dark energy will be significant (more than 10 million light years).
>
> "This unified theory is consistent with general characterizations of dark energy and dark matter, and further tests of the theory up to measured precisions of cosmic observations are certainly crucial for an eventual validation of the theory," Wang added.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the one on dark matter and energy ?

Comment: I am in no position to evaluate a new gravitational theory thus my answer is only on the particle paper. They have published this, the journal says  articles are peer reviewed. I will have to wait and see what type of impact  the paper has.

Comment: Here is a description of their gravitational paper http://newsinfo.iu.edu/news-archive/23053.html

Comment: @ anna v - I would be very pleasantly surprised if the theoreticians (I'm one) give it a thumbs up without hearing from the experimentalists, so what you have hit upon is a very weird situation. There has been so much of an outrage against the promotion of string theory as a scientific discipline, in the absence of experimental backing, that even the theory guys have adopted a cautious approach - ``looks fine, but these things are ultimately settled by experimentation''. So, weird as it may sound, irrespective of how good an idea may be, `social acceptance' does start from you guys. :)

Comment: @New_new_newbie the experiments are used to validate theoretical models and ultimately validate theories. One can have beautiful theoretical constructs, they are called mathematics. If they do not describe measurable quantities  they just remain in the mathematical archives. Sometimes, as with Riemannian geometry, a brilliant choice by a theoretician leads to models that can be validated. So it is not social acceptance, but a slow build up of a theory of everything in nature, by using mathematical models. In the second paper, first theorists have to judge, if it does all it claims

Comment: i.e. can include the standard model of particle physics and all the data known from astrophysics, and then suggest experiments that would differentiate the standard cosmological model from the new proposal. Then the experimenters come in.

Comment: @ anna v - Yes, but peer review takes care of that. You don't just believe the results unless they are reviewed. What I'm addressing is, even after the theoretical constructs stand validated, a beautiful construct has no value without experimental backing. String theory is of course a case in point. People respect that, that's why they have the cautious approach that I mentioned - ``looks fine, but these are ultimately settled by experimentation''.